# What kind actions could be open to Bulk Editing in a Data Grid?

Tags: data, data-tables, actions

For a Data Table with Bulk Actions enabled, we will have 2 types of Data:

1. Single Select Eg. Enable/Disable, etc.,
2. Multi-Select Eg. User access to multiple accounts. (refer image below)

So, my question is, what kind of properties should be exposed to bulk edit?

[image: Screen One]

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of an awkward question.

Perhaps you should start with the basic premise... *as a user of this system, what are some of the items I would want to edit on mass?* Then your next question would be what is a good approach to allow users to perform these edits. In the broadest sense, if the user needs to bulk change everything, then the functionality should allow them to do so.

Should they user be allowed to change properties that aren't shown on the table? Yes, if they need to. Having the bulk edit option at the top of the table probably isn't the best way to handle this sort of update. You'll want a confirmation step when updating stuff that's important and the user can't directly verify the changes.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is behind the actions.

1. Edit icon: if users are editing unique characteristics, then no bulk editing, if shared characteristics, then bulk editing.
2. Delete: can be bulked.
3. Copy: can be bulked.
4. Statistics (?) — depends on whether you can show all this data from different files in one graph, if yes, then bulk (but showing more than 10-15 players in one chart could make it unreadable, depending on the chart type), if no, then not.

You could also get the actions out of the table. Right now they are repeated with every item in the list, and it adds the noise. If you group them in a floating toolbar on top of the chart, it could resolve this issue. Plus, then you could add more actions without worrying they are taking too much space.